# Pushing an item to an observableArray created with the mapping plugin after it's created

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got a knockout View Model that looks like this:

```
var TagViewModel = function (allPrincipals) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable(tagName);

    var principalMapping = {
        create: function(options) {
            return {
                label: options.data.name,
                key: options.data.type + '___|' + options.data.name,
                icon: options.data.type == "User" ? "img/misc/user20.png" : "img/misc/group20.png"
            };
        },
        key: function(data) {
            return data.key;
        }
    };

    self.allPrincipals = ko.mapping.fromJS(allPrincipals, principalMapping);
}
```

`allPrincipals` would look something like this:

```
var allPrincipals = [{name: "Alex" type: "User"}, {name: "John", type: "User"}, {name: "Staff", type: "Group}]
```

So, when the viewModel is created, we have something like:

```
var vm = new TagViewModel(allPrincipals);
```

This works fine.

However, in the view model, I need to be able to push a new item in to the allPrincipals observable array (created by the mapping plugin)

What's the best way to do this?

So, for example, there's a function on the view model:

```
self.addPrincipal = function(prinipal){
    //allPrincipals.push(?)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class for creating `Principal` objects:

```
function Principal(data){
   var self = this;

   self.label = data.name;
   self.key = data.type + '___|' + data.name;
   self.icon = data.type == "User" ? "img/misc/user20.png" : "img/misc/group20.png";
}
```

And then use it in mapping options and in `addPrincipal` function:

```
var principalMapping = {
    create: function(options) {
        return new Principal(options.data);
    },
    key: function(data) {
        return data.key;
    }
};

self.addPrincipal = function(prinipal){
    self.allPrincipals.push(new Principal(prinipal));
}
```